# Spring @Procedure and List as return

Tags: spring, postgresql, stored-procedures, spring-data

Anyone know how to use @Procedure spring annotation with a postgres procedure (function) that returns a setof?

The code below does not work:

```
public interface CalculatedEventRepository extends CrudRepository<CalculatedEvent, CalculatedEventId> {    

        @Procedure(name = 'CalculatedEvent.calculate')
        List<CalculatedEvent> calcular(@Param("yearMonth") Integer yearMonth)
}
```

Entity

```
@Entity
@NamedStoredProcedureQuery(name = 'CalculatedEvent.calculate', procedureName = 'fn_calcula_eventos',
                resultClasses = CalculatedEvent.class,
                parameters = [
                        @StoredProcedureParameter( mode = ParameterMode.IN, name = 'yearMonth', type = Integer.class),
                        @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.OUT, name = 'res', type = List.class)
            ]
        )
public class CalculatedEvent implements Serializable {
...
}
```

However I have the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Type cannot be null
    org.hibernate.procedure.internal.AbstractParameterRegistrationImpl.setHibernateType(AbstractParameterRegistrationImpl.java:182)
    org.hibernate.procedure.internal.AbstractParameterRegistrationImpl.<init>(AbstractParameterRegistrationImpl.java:131)
    org.hibernate.procedure.internal.AbstractParameterRegistrationImpl.<init>(AbstractParameterRegistrationImpl.java:106)
    org.hibernate.procedure.internal.NamedParameterRegistration.<init>(NamedParameterRegistration.java:50)
    org.hibernate.procedure.internal.ProcedureCallImpl.<init>(ProcedureCallImpl.java:221)
    org.hibernate.procedure.internal.ProcedureCallMementoImpl.makeProcedureCall(ProcedureCallMementoImpl.java:83)
    org.hibernate.jpa.internal.StoredProcedureQueryImpl.<init>(StoredProcedureQueryImpl.java:80)
    org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.createNamedStoredProcedureQuery(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:982)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:344)
    com.sun.proxy.$Proxy70.createNamedStoredProcedureQuery(Unknown Source)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:291)
    com.sun.proxy.$Proxy70.createNamedStoredProcedureQuery(Unknown Source)
    org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.StoredProcedureJpaQuery.newNamedStoredProcedureQuery(StoredProcedureJpaQuery.java:119)
    org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.StoredProcedureJpaQuery.createStoredProcedure(StoredProcedureJpaQuery.java:109)
    org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.StoredProcedureJpaQuery.doCreateQuery(StoredProcedureJpaQuery.java:68)
    org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.StoredProcedureJpaQuery.createQuery(StoredProcedureJpaQuery.java:58)
    org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$ProcedureExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:295)
    org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:74)
    org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:97)
    org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:88)
    org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:395)
    org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:373)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:486)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodIntercceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:122)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
    com.sun.proxy.$Proxy73.calcular(Unknown Source)
    br.com.well.coney.persistence.repository.CalculatedEventRepository$calcular.call(Unknown Source)
    org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
    org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
    org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
    br.com.well.coney.application.implementation.CalculatedEventServiceImpl.calculateIncludes(CalculatedEventServiceImpl.groovy:80)
    br.com.well.coney.application.implementation.CalculatedEventServiceImpl.this$2$calculateIncludes(CalculatedEventServiceImpl.groovy)
    br.com.well.coney.application.implementation.CalculatedEventServiceImpl$this$2$calculateIncludes.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
    org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:49)
    org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
    org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:145)
    br.com.well.coney.application.implementation.CalculatedEventServiceImpl.calculate(CalculatedEventServiceImpl.groovy:22)
    br.com.well.coney.application.CalculatedEventService$calculate.call(Unknown Source)
    org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
    org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
    org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
    br.com.well.coney.application.remote.ChartResource.getExpenses(ChartResource.groovy:71)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:777)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:706)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:877)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:857)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:618)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:85)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:57)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
```

PS.: The function works fine on database.

Answer (score 0):

This is a reported bug
https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJPA-652.

I struggled with the same issue just to find out there's nothing to do. You can try to switch to EclipseLink. The link above mentions this sample: https://gist.github.com/thomasdarimont/129bc15d0ccc459610c2.